# If $\sin(x)+\cos(x)=y$, for what value(s) of $y$ can $\sin(x)\cos(x)=1$?

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\sin(x)+\cos(x)=y$, for what value(s) of $y$ can $\sin(x)\cos(x)=1$?

Squaring Both sides

$$(1+2\cos x\sin x)=y^2$$

I am stuck here. Can you square both sides, as $\sin(x)\cos(x)$ cannot be equal to $1$ in the real domain?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92722/discussion-on-question-by-devrshi-modi-central-peel-ss-if-sinx-cosxy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\sin x \cos x = 1$ **iff** $\sin^2 x + 2 \sin x \cos x + \cos^2 x = (\sin x + \cos x)^2 = 3$.

Note that $\sin x + \cos x = \sqrt{2} \sin (x+ {\pi \over 4})$ hence you are looking for solutions to 
$\sin^2 (x+ {\pi \over 4}) = {3 \over 2}$.

One can find solutions to $\sin^2 y = {3 \over 2}$ by expanding $\sin$ in terms
of exponentials to get
$(e^{iy}-e^{-iy})^2 = -6$, or $(e^{i2y})^2 + 4 (e^{i2y}) +1 = 0$.

Solving this gives
$y = {1 \over 2} (\pi -i \log (2 \pm \sqrt{3}))+m\pi$ ($m$ an arbitrary
integer), and hence
$x = ({1 \over 4}+m) \pi - i {1 \over 2} \log (2 \pm \sqrt{3})$ ($m$ just flips the sign, the $\pm$ has no effect on the result).

In particular, the answer to the question is that if $\sin x \cos x =1$ then $\sin x + \cos x = \pm \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: For which complex numbers x does this hold to be true??

Comment: I have a formula for all solutions above?

Answer (score 2):

$$(1+2\cos x\sin x)^2=y^2\implies \cos x\sin x=\frac{\pm y-1}2$$

And thus you need to solve

$$\frac{\pm y-1}2=1\implies \pm y=3...\text{what can you conclude?}$$

Of course, much easy, as you say at the end of your question, to observe that

$$1=\cos x\sin x=\frac{\sin 2x}2$$

and this has no solution at all in $\;\Bbb R\;$ .

Comment: so can you make a substituion as sinxcosx=1, therefore,  1+ 2(1) = 3

Comment: 3 = y^2 so y = +-sqrt(3)

Comment: would these solutions of y be correct in the complex domain??

Comment: What is shown above is $\;y=\pm 3\;$ , not $\;y=\pm\sqrt3\;$ ...and yes, this would work in the complex plane, but not only these...